# Is there a maximum building height in Minecraft, and why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to build an OGame Death Star model in Minecraft, and I started doing it on the highest mountain I could find, for some reason... I built one third of it and blam, can't build any further! Why is that? Or is that a bug?

Comment: Since this question is 9 years old, it's unlikely that this will help the original questioner, but for anyone *else* who finds themself in this situation, you can use the [`/clone` command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/clone) to move or copy large builds around, which may be helpful if you run into the height limit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Yes

The Minecraft world is 256 blocks (as of Minecraft 1.2) from top to bottom. The reason for the height restriction is that the Minecraft world is made of 16x16x256 'chunks'. These are loaded into memory and rendered starting with the ones closest to the player. A 3D world of chunks (where the world is 'infinite' vertically as well as horizontally) is a whole lot more complex than a 2D world of chunks to manage, and optimizing for smooth gameplay would be a challenge. 256 is a convenient number that's a power of 2 (making it align nicely in memory).

Note that there is *also* a separate build height on servers. In the `server.properties` file, there is a property `max-build-height` which defaults to 256. Server admins can lower this value to prevent players placing blocks above a certain height, but it will not prevent natural terrain from spawning above this level, or players climbing natural structures above this height.

Although it is theoretically possible for a mod to increase the height limit of the map, I can't find any that work with the current version of Minecraft or are in active development.

Comment: Thanks, that's a cool explanation. But come on, it's Java, **nothing** aligns nicely in memory.

Comment: The link to the height mod is dead (and also obsolete). Are there any mods for 1.5/1.5.1?

Comment: Seconding tombull89: the build height can be twiddled with an NBT editor (I believe) or `server.properties` now.

Comment: Hasn't a recent update increased that height limit?  Or am I misremembering a spec?

Comment: @Zibbobz You are correct. The height limit used to be 128, but when Minecraft switched to the Anvil file format, the limit was increased to 256

Comment: I thought it was 271 for some reason. Are there any other significant values in minecraft that are 271 and I may have been confusing with the height limit?

Comment: No... Not as far as I know. Most things are powers of two.

Comment: It's for memory reasons. 256 is the highest value which can be stored in a single unsigned byte. The previous format was limited to 128 because it used a format which allowed negative numbers (though they were not used).

Comment: @Studoku I didn't know this, do you have a source on the negative numbers thing?

Comment: I somehow thought the build limit had been much more expanded so that you could set it to 512, etc., but I am wrong! That's worth the bounty. :) … just as soon as 41 minutes elapse, that is.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did wonder, I spent a long time trying to find something new!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie `just as soon as 41 minutes elapse, that is – SevenSidedDie 1 hour ago` :-P

Comment: Self-correction: just as soon as 41 minutes and child interruptions are past. :)

Comment: @fredley Comp Sci degree and a very likely assumption. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: This is outdated now, the new high is 320 as of 1.18

Answer (score 4):

The height in unmodded Minecraft is restricted. From the bottom of the world to the highest possible point is 256 meters, or blocks.

Comment: Btw, if you want to check at what height you are, press the f3 key and check the Y value displayed.

Answer (score 2):

As of 21w06a the build height has changed, it is now from y=-64 to y=320. 64 blocks have been added to both the top and bottom of the world, since this is still a snapshot this is subject to change.
The total build height is now 384 blocks and can be modified using datapacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go 256 blocks above in the overworld, but in the nether, there is bedrock above and underneath the nether.

Answer (score 0):

The build height limit is 256 blocks, as of pre - 1.17. The Minecraft world is made of 16x256x16 chunks. In 1.18 (Caves and Cliffs Part 2) they have changed the build height limit to 320 blocks. Also, chunks are now 16x384x16. In the Nether, you can only go up to 128 as there is bedrock at the top of the Nether.

Answer (score -1):

if you play in the snapshot 20w49a you can get blocks placed at a y-coordinate from 500 to -500 but it is buggy and requires a datapack like this: https://github.com/onnowhere/examples

Comment: 500 to -500 what?

Comment: @Penguin Please don't downvote, this is true. Datapacks are able to change parts of dimensions including the min and max height.

Comment: @RayWu I never downvoted nor said it was not true. He just doesn't specify what "500" to "-500" is. 500 what?

Comment: @Penguin Then edit it yourself to say y coordinates.

Comment: @RayWu I didn't know that, hence why I asked. Also I can't edit stuff without it taking a bit to be approved anyway

Comment: @RayWu Besides, it is the author's responsibility to clarify language, not that of users posting comments.

Comment: @Joachim I agree, I was just under the impression that Penguin knew what the numbers were referring to and was suggesting a change.

Comment: @RayWu Ah, okay :)

Answer (score -3):

If you want to build very high, build in the nether... That way you have plenty of space to go... Infinity. But in the over world, in order to build to infinity you need mods. The reason why there is a height limit is because the terrain would generate way to high, and the computer would lag or buffer and crash. The x and y dimensions also have a limit. 30,000,000 both sides. However, again, I have a question? Can't mojang set two height limits? One for the terrain, which is 256, or 512 and the building which is infinity?

Comment: If you have a comment, you should put it after the question. Not as an answer.

Comment: The nether has the same build height restrictions as the overworld. I'm not clear where you get the idea you can build infinitely high in the nether.

Comment: that's not really why there's a max height limit...